# Linking Comparator to JButton

Tags: java, sorting, jbutton, jlist, comparator

**How do I link the Comparator with the JButton?**

I have a "ascent", "descent" button. I want to sort the names in my panel as I press the buttons. I want to use a comparator class to sort them.

I know this is a lot of code. Sorry!

I have 4 classes: MainWindow, JListData, Start, MyComparator

**MainWindow:**

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JTextField txName = null;
private JButton butOK = new JButton("ok");
private JButton butDelete = new JButton("delete");

private JButton butAscent = new JButton("ascending");
private JButton butDescent = new JButton("descending");

private int selectedIndex =-1;
private String selectedName = null;

private JListData dataModel = null;


public MainWindow() throws HeadlessException {
    this("Demo JList");
}


public MainWindow(String titel) throws HeadlessException {
    super(titel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE ); 



    //ContentPane 

    Container cpane = this.getContentPane(); 
    cpane.setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // Festlegung des Layouts

    JPanel pnlOben = new JPanel();

    txName = new JTextField(20);

    pnlUp.add(txName);
    pnlUp.add(butOK);
    pnlUp.add(butDelete);

    pnlUp.add(butAscent);
    pnlUp.add(butDescent);

    cpane.add(pnlUp, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // Listener
    butOK.addActionListener(new ActionAdapter1());
    butDelete.addActionListener(new ActionAdapter2());

    butAscent.addActionListener(new ActionAdapter3());
    //butDescent.addActionListener(new ActionAdapter4());

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(); 

    JPanel panel = makeTextPanel();        
    tabbedPane.addTab("A-Z", null, panel, "Name with \"" + "A-Z" + "\"");           

    // JTabbedPane on ContentPane 

    cpane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.pack();

}

public JPanel makeTextPanel() 
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(false); 

    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1)); 

    dataModel = new JListData(); 

    JList liste = new JList(dataModel);         

    liste.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL); 

    liste.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); 

    liste.setVisibleRowCount(-1);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(liste); 

    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 260)); 

    liste.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionAdapter(liste)); 

    panel.add(scrollPane);     
    return panel;
} 



class ListSelectionAdapter implements ListSelectionListener
{
    JList myList;

    public ListSelectionAdapter(JList list)
    {
        myList= list;
    }

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent ev ) 
    {
        if(ev.getValueIsAdjusting() == false){
          selectedName = (String)myList.getSelectedValue(); 
          System.out.println("selected String " + selectedName);

          selectedIndex = myList.getSelectedIndex(); 
          System.out.println("selected Index " + selectedIndex);

        }
    }
}// end of inner class ListSelectionAdapter



class ActionAdapter1 implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("ok Button " + txName.getText());

        dataModel.addElement(txName.getText());
    }
}



class ActionAdapter2 implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("delete Button " + selectedName);

        if(selectedIndex > -1){
            dataModel.removeElement(selectedName, selectedIndex);
        }
    }
}


**// SHOULD SORTING BE HERE?! #help**

class ActionAdapter3 implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {         
    }   
}}
```

**JListData:**

```
public class JListData extends AbstractListModel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Vector <String> dlist; 

public JListData() {
    dlist = new Vector <String> (); 
    makeData();  
}

private Vector <String> makeData()
{
    String[] data = {"Otto", "Gustav", "Hugo", "Anna", "Emil", "Marianne"}; 

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        dlist.addElement( (String) data[i]);
    }
    return dlist; 
}

public Object getElementAt(int index)
{
    return dlist.elementAt(index); 
}

public int getSize()
{
    return dlist.size();
}

public void addElement(String s){

    dlist.addElement(s);

    this.fireIntervalAdded(this, dlist.size()-1, dlist.size());
}

public void removeElement(String s, int index){

    System.out.println("removeElement: s = " 
            + s);
    System.out.println("removeElement: index = " 
            + index);

    dlist.remove(s);


    int index0 = index;
    int index1 = index;
    this.fireIntervalRemoved(this, index0, index1);
}}
```

**Start:**

```
public class Start {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    window.setVisible(true); 
}}
```

**MyComparator:**

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<JListData> {

public int compare(JListData name1, JListData name2) {

    int tmp = 0;

    tmp = name1.getName.compareTo(name2.getName());

    return tmp;

}}
```

Comment: where is your implemented `Comparator` ?

Comment: in this case you don't need to implement comparator , your datas are Strings , you can sort the before adding them into your jlist

Comment: I dont know how to implement the comparator and use it for the button

Comment: we don't implement Comparator for the button , button is just a thing that do something for us from its actionperformed method

Comment: if you want to see the implementation look [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/Comparator-interface-in-collection-framework)

Comment: then edit your question , i'll answer it

Comment: I have a "ascent", "descent" button. I want to sort the names in my panel as I press the buttons.
I want to use a comparator class to sort them.

Comment: do you see the link ?

Comment: Yes thanks for the link. I just don't know how to use it with the button.

Comment: write the comparator , then i'll tell you how to use it for button

Comment: I added the Comparator. Did I do this correct?

Comment: yes , how do you call it for sort your `data` array ? (hint : using Collections.sort)

Comment: I don't understand your question :/